# Flutter: can l call the same Future, first with "then()" followed by "await", without incurring in race condition issues?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, future

I came across this piece of code on SO:

**EDIT:the following code snippet is fully functional, I'm trying to understand if beside "working", can it lead to errors due to a possible race condition**

```
  if (!_downloaders.containsKey(page)) {
    _downloaders[page] = NetworkProvider().getRecentPodcasts(page);
    _downloaders[page].then((_) => _downloaders.remove(page));
  }
  final podcasts = await _downloaders[page];
```

and I cannot wrap my head around one part:

```
_downloaders[page].then((_) => _downloaders.remove(page));
```

here after we added a `future` to this `Map`, we execute the `future` by calling `then()`,
because we want that after the `future` has finished, the `future` is removed from the `Map`.

Here all is clear, but on the next line, we call `await`, on the `Future` that has been added to the `Map`, and which will be removed soon.

I cannot really understand how this is good code, as it looks to me that when the Future is called with the `then()`, I know that the code execution doesn't stop for the `then()` (but it does for `await`) , but isn't there a remote case where it might get to the `await` part, but the `future` is NOT inside the `Map` anymore, as it has been already removed?

Or this can never happen, and if so, can you explain me the inner workings, so I can fully graps this concept and improve my codebase

Comment: maybe it will help you https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html you can wrap all yours Future in it and wait for the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I cannot really understand how this is good code, as it looks to me that when the Future is called with the `then()`, I know that the code execution doesn't stop for the `then()` (but it does for `await`) , but isn't there a remote case where it might get to the `await` part, but the `future` is NOT inside the `Map` anymore, as it has been already removed?

`Future.then()` does not execute the `Future`'s computation. `Future.then()` only registers a callback.

The cited code usually shouldn't be racy. `Future`s are normally asynchronous; even if the `Future`'s computation is already complete, the `.then()` callback will not execute until the Dart runtime returns to the event loop, which in this case would happen at the `await` line.  You can observe this:

```dart
void main() async {
  print('Constructing Future');
  var future = Future.sync(() => print('Ran future'));
  print('Constructed Future; registering callback');
  // ignore: unawaited_futures
  future.then((_) => print('Ran .then() callback'));
  print('Registered callback; awaiting');
  await future;
  print('Done');
}
```

which will print:

```
Constructing Future
Ran future
Constructed Future; registering callback
Registered callback; awaiting
Ran .then() callback
Done
```

It's possible (but unlikely) that the code could be racy in pathological cases.  For example, Flutter provides a [`SynchronousFuture`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/SynchronousFuture-class.html) class that implements the `Future` interface but executes its `.then()` callback synchronously upon registration.  However, that is rather unusual (and which is why the documentation for `SynchronousFuture` explicitly discourages using it).  For that to happen, the `NetworkProvider().getRecentPodcasts` implementation would have to explicitly return a `SynchronousFuture` (or some equivalent implementation).